# Get tag/feature/landuse meta information for latitude longitude in openstreetmap

Tags: openstreetmap, metadata, latitude-longitude

I need the possibility to find the underlying ground information of a given location (set by latLng) - not an area!

I already tried the nominatim reverse search, but it lacks the landuse information. Here's an example query: http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=52.5487429714954&lon=-1.81602098644987&zoom=18&addressdetails=1

How do I enforce the output of the landuse here, which would likely be "residential"?

Comment: Please don't crosspost anymore https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/32083/get-tagfeaturelanduse-for-latitude-longitude

Comment: Sorry for that. At least someone answered to my question there. The solution for the problem is a `coord-query`, or an `is_in` as quoted here: http://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/32083/get-tagfeaturelanduse-meta-information-for-latitude-longitude-in-openstreetmap/32138

Comment: FYI: There is a catch with the `is_in` approach. This will only match areas with a name. Areas / ways without a name will only be found if you search them by the `around` search.